# HQL to SQL in Java 5

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Is it possible to translate in run time, the HSQL statement to SQL using EntityManager?

I've found this solution but I don't have the sessionFactory, I have EntityManager

```
protected String toSql(String hqlQueryText) {
    if (sessionFactory != null && hqlQueryText != null && hqlQueryText.trim().length() > 0) {
        final QueryTranslatorFactory translatorFactory = new ASTQueryTranslatorFactory();
        final SessionFactoryImplementor factory = (SessionFactoryImplementor) sessionFactory;
        final QueryTranslator translator = translatorFactory.createQueryTranslator(hqlQueryText, hqlQueryText,
        Collections.EMPTY_MAP, factory);
        translator.compile(Collections.EMPTY_MAP, false);
        return translator.getSQLString();
        }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you got the EntityManager you can use the following piece of code to get the SessionFactory:

```
EntityManager em = ...
SessionFactory sf = ((EntityManagerFactoryImpl)em.getEntityManagerFactory()).getSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't find getEntityManagerFactory in the EntityManager API http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html

Comment: It's available since JPA 2.0. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getEntityManagerFactory()